# Date Time picker does not save selected date to the database

Tags: php, laravel, datepicker

In my laravel project, I want to save Datepicker selected date to the database. But my code saves date as "**01-01-1970**" and **not the selected date** from the date picker. 
I tried to fix it by going through many codes. But no luck.

Here is the controller store function.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $qualification = new qualification();

            $qualification->from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->from));
            $qualification->to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->to));

            $qualification->save();

            return redirect()->route('qualification.index')->with('success','Data Added');
        }
```

Here is the blade.php

```
 <label for="date">From:</label><input type="text" name="date" value="" />
 <label for="date">To:</label><input type="text" name="date" value="" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1995,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
  });
});
</script>
```

Please help me to save the selected date to the database. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get values of $request->from and $request->to in your controller but in HTML both the text fields are named as date.

It Should be Like

HTML:

```
 <label for="date">From:</label><input type="text" class="date" name="from" value="" />
 <label for="date">To:</label><input type="text" class="date" name="to" value="" />
```

In js

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.date').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1995,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please read the answer carefully, i have added a class attribute on both input and also change the selector in js code.

Comment: add ```class="date"``` on both the inputs and in js make it  ```$('.date').daterangepicker({...})``` from   ```$('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({..})```

Comment: If the user didn't select a date from the datepicker, I want to pass the value as NULL to the database. So I added `autoUpdateInput: false,` and `function(chosen_date) { $('.date').val(chosen_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); }` to the above script. If the user didn't select a date, it again saves the date as **01-01-1970 instead of keeping the field as NULL**. Any idea to fix it? Thanks

Comment: ```if($request->has('from')){
    $qualification->from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->from));
}
else {
    $qualification->from = NULL;
}

if($request->has('to')){
    $qualification->from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->to));
}
else {
    $qualification->from = NULL;
}```

Comment: try the above code,if it works for you kindly up vote the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker:   true,
            showDropdowns:      true,
            minYear:            1901,
            maxYear:            parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10),
            locale: {
                format:         'DD-MM-YYYY'
            }        
        }, function(start, end, label) {
            var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
            //alert("You are " + years + " years old!");
        });
    });
</script>
```